# vue-izitoast function return value

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

i use izitoast,
i need use $route in button function in vue-izitoast but it doesn't work
or
i don't know how return value of this function to use in vue

```
                buttons: [
                    [
                        "<button><b>yes</b></button>",
                        function() {
                            axios
                                .post(`/student/rooms`, {
                                    room_id: room.id
                                })
                                .then(res => {
                                  this.$router.push(`/student/rooms/${room.id}`);
                                });
                        },
                        true
                    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use an Arrow Function to get local scope. Try this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <button @click="test">TEST</button>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    test() {
      this.$toast.show('Welcome!', 'Hey', {
        position: 'topCenter',
        buttons: [
          [
            '<button>Change Router</button>',
            (instance, toast) => {
              this.$router.push({ name: 'About' });
            },
            true,
          ],
        ],
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)